# Include file in foreach loop php

Tags: php, foreach, include

I have an array of ids, and for each id, I want to include a file, and send the id to the include-file, but after the first id, the other ids are empty. Why are the other ids not passed through the include-file?

```
    $ids = array(1, 2, 3);
    foreach($ids as $id) {
         $id = $id;
         include_once("file.php");
         echo $path . "<br />"; // comes from include-file
    }
```

When I echo my $id in the include-file, I get '1', but the other two ids are empty?

Comment: Return will exit loop

Comment: Yoy dont need to redeclare $id since it exists. So use only the include in your loop delete/comment de return and id line

Comment: I'm sorry, It's echo, i changed this

Comment: So if I understood correctly your file.php is the same for each id. Than use include instead of include once. Include once will only fire once

Comment: also one more thing, suppose you have N ids, it's a really bad thing to include one file N times. instead include **once** a type of functions file and run a specific function which will return the $path you are seeking, and !important do this outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this problem, because you are using [inlcude_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), this makes exactly what the name suggests, it is including your file only once.

You need [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). By the way, you can drop `$id=$id;`, because you have $id already defined in the foreach here: `foreach( $ids as $id )`.

**Try this instead:**

```
$ids = array( 1, 2, 3 );
foreach( $ids as $id ) {
    include( "file.php" );
    echo $path . "<br />"; // comes from include-file
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the include-file, I declared a function, why is this a problem? Because when I remove the function, I get each id.

Comment: This is because in your example the function would be declared 3 times due to the 3 `include? in the foreach, you can declare a function only once in php.

Comment: @swidmann this comment saved me hours of headache; I was doing the same thing as OP and didn't realize that my loop with include wasn't working because I had declared functions in the include.  Thanks!